# LookupAccountName Always Fails With Error 122 (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)

Tags: c++, c, windows, wifi, sid

Perhaps somebody can enlighten me here.

I'm attempting to automate a WiFi connection process where the SSID is determined by a serial number. Since this is always different, I figured I need to save a temporary profile each time I wish to connect.

`WlanSaveTemporaryProfile()` wants a `LPCWSTR strAllUserProfileSecurity` to define permissions for this profile. So far the rabbit hole has led me to try using `LookupAccountNameW()`. I have tried to `AllocateAndInitializeSid()` to no avail. I tried plugging in an empty buffer with the same result. In both cases, I get an error 122, which says the buffer was too small.

Any aid here is sincerely appreciated.

---

Here's the relevant code. Mostly constructed from examples in Microsoft's documentation.

```
DWORD GetStringSecurityDescriptor(
    PWCHAR ps_securityDescriptor, /* This needs to be populated when this function completes. */
    PULONG pul_securityDescriptorLen,
    LPWSTR ps_accountName
    )
{
    DWORD dw_result = NULL; 
    DWORD dw_lastError = NULL;
    DWORD dw_bufferSizeOfUserAccount = NULL;

    /* Create a security descriptor for the profile. */
    SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR secDesc;
    bool success = InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&secDesc, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
    if (!success)
    {
        wprintf(L"Security Descriptor Initialization Failed.\n");
    }

    PSID p_userSid = NULL;
    /* Attempt 2: Straight up malloc the memory. Doesn't work any better.*/
    //p_userSid = malloc(100);

    /* Attempt 1: Allocate and Initialize an SID for LookupAccountNameW(). */
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY auth = SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY;
    BOOL b_sidReady = AllocateAndInitializeSid(
        &auth,
        6,
        SECURITY_NULL_RID,
        SECURITY_WORLD_RID,
        SECURITY_LOCAL_RID,
        SECURITY_LOCAL_LOGON_RID,
        SECURITY_CREATOR_OWNER_RID,
        SECURITY_CREATOR_GROUP_RID,
        0, 0,
        &p_userSid
        );

    LPDWORD buf = &dw_bufferSizeOfUserAccount;
    WCHAR domainName[1000] = { 0 }; // Perhaps DNLEN + 1 was too small?
    DWORD domainNameLen = 1000;
    SID_NAME_USE use = SidTypeUser;

    // Currently failing. dw_bufferSizeOfUserAccount still recieves a 28, so that wasn't it.
    success = LookupAccountNameW(
        NULL, 
        ps_accountName, 
        p_userSid, 
        buf, 
        domainName, 
        &domainNameLen, 
        &use);
    if (!success) 
    {
        dw_lastError = GetLastError();
        switch (dw_lastError)
        {
        case ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER: // LookupAccountNameW() always ends up here.
            wprintf(L"The data area passed to a system call is too small.\n");
            FreeSid(p_userSid);
            return dw_lastError;
        default:
            wprintf(L"Looking up Account Name failed. See Error 0x%x.\n", dw_lastError);
            FreeSid(p_userSid);
            return dw_lastError;
        }
    }

// ... more code irrelevant to this problem...

}
```

Comment: Microdoft documentation: "`ReferencedDomainName` ... If this parameter is NULL, the function returns the required buffer size". You can call this function twice - one for buffer size estimation and the second one will be successful, if it was a problem, because you'll allocate correct amount of memory.

Comment: Moreover: "`cbSid`

A pointer to a variable. On input, this value specifies the size, in bytes, of the Sid buffer. If the function fails because the buffer is too small or if `cbSid` is zero, this variable receives the required buffer size." It looks like you have some problems here, because you pass pointer to zero value in this parameter (`DWORD dw_bufferSizeOfUserAccount = NULL;` and later: `LPDWORD buf = &dw_bufferSizeOfUserAccount;`)

Comment: How could I miss that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great thanks to [Georgy Firsov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5108828/georgy-firsov)!

I missed a statement in the documentation.

By calculating the size of the SID and storing it in `dw_bufferSizeOfUserAccount`, the function ran successfully.

```
dw_bufferSizeOfUserAccount = GetLengthSid(p_userSid);
```